# How can/should I create automatic link between ui forms and data members in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

It is a generic problem, I don't know how it is usually handled and I am looking for a *good* (???) way to do it:

I have a ui with many numerical forms corresponding to the various options of my program.
I have a couple of structures using the data provided by the ui.

I need to synchronize the form and the data obviously. Right now I do it manually and I write this kind of functions :

```
Options GetOptions(){ //fetches data from ui and stores it in my structure
        options.fil.alpha = ui.fil_consecutive_alpha->value();
        options.fil.beta = ui.fil_consecutive_beta->value();
        options.fil.gamma = ui.fil_consecutive_gamma->value();
        options.fil.delta = ui.fil_consecutive_delta->value();
        options.fil.k_max = ui.fil_consecutive_k_max->value();
        options.fil.radius = ui.fil_consecutive_radius->value();
        options.fil.omega = ui.fil_consecutive_omega->value();
        options.fil.side_length = ui.fil_consecutive_side_length->value();
        options.fil.norm = ui.fil_consecutive_norm->value();
        options.fil.consecutive_images = true;
}
void SetOptions(const Options& options){ //update ui forms with the loaded options sdtored in the structure
        ui.fil_consecutive_alpha->setValue(options.fil.alpha);
        ui.fil_consecutive_beta->setValue(options.fil.beta );
        ui.fil_consecutive_gamma->setValue(options.fil.gamma);
        ui.fil_consecutive_delta->setValue(options.fil.delta);
        ui.fil_consecutive_k_max->setValue(options.fil.k_max);
        ui.fil_consecutive_radius->setValue(options.fil.radius);
        ui.fil_consecutive_omega->setValue(options.fil.omega);
        ui.fil_consecutive_side_length->setValue(options.fil.side_length);
        ui.fil_consecutive_norm->setValue(options.fil.norm);
    }
```

Every time I add a ui field I have to update the set and get functions. These function look dumb, and it is getting worse with time, and I have been told computers are good at dealing with this kind of repetitive dumb tasks.

So, do you think it would be a good idea to somehow say that every ui form that starts with "fil_consecutive_" should be associated with the structure options.fil ? How could I achieve that programatically ?

Comment: You could use [Qt properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html). You'd need to subclass `QObject` for your data structures, but then you can do: `options.fil.setProperty("alpha", ...)`, which will then call an associated setter function.

Comment: That would work fine for accessing my data structure; how can I programatically scan every ui form name to systematically access the forms in my ui and filter them by name ? Or could I filter them another way ?

Comment: You could iterate your forms child objects and use objectName() to get the name of the control (i.e. a string representation of the variable name - see this being set in your generated ui_xxx.h file).  Then link it to the property somehow based on that name.  Maybe you call the property the same name as the control.

Comment: There are meta data but to have them you have to define properties and this requires more amount of code, so there is no point to use this solution in this case. Problem is that class field don't have meta data until you define them (setter getter and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give you an idea. You can set [objectName](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#objectName-prop) to your forms. If you set ObjectName in Designer that will be done in generated ui.hh file. Use QList to store all specific forms and QMap for Options.

```
...
// set form's name somewhere
ui.fil_consecutive_alpha->setObjectName("fil_consecutive_omega");
...

...
// colect forms like this
QObjectList list = this.children();
QObjectList forms = QObjectList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    if list[i].objectName().startsWith("fil_consecutive_")
         forms << list[i];
...

...
// then your function will be
void getOptions(QObjectList forms){
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < forms.size(); ++i) {
         QString opt = forms[i].objectName().mid(QString("fil_consecurive_").length())
         options.fil[opt] = forms[i].property("value");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Q_PROPERTY and objectName(), that's what I was looking for, thank you :)